# Manifest Based Event Won't Take Event Data

Tags: c++, event-log

I'm attempting to write an event to the Windows Event Log. All works fine spare one item: I cannot seem to get event data to show in the event log when writing the event to it.

Here is a copy of my manifest:

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
<instrumentationManifest xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events eventman.xsd" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/    win/2004/08/events" xmlns:win="http://manifests.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/windows/events" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:trace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
    <instrumentation>
        <events>
            <provider 
                name="OperationFilter" 
                guid="{B7FB08C2-AB1B-448F-BFE0-FB09BEF3659D}" 
                symbol="OPERATION_FILTER" 
                resourceFileName="C:\Program Files\TestBindParameters\TestBindParameters.exe" 
                messageFileName="C:\Program Files\TestBindParameters\TestBindParameters.exe">
                <events>
                    <event 
                        symbol="OPERATION_DB_ERROR" 
                        value="1" 
                        version="0" 
                        channel="Operation-Filter-Admin" 
                        level="win:Error" 
                        message="$(string.OperationFilter.event.1.message)" 
                        template="Operation-Filter-Messages"></event>
                </events>
                <levels></levels>
                <channels>
          <channel 
              name="Operation-Filter-Admin" 
              chid="Operation-Filter-Admin" 
              symbol="OPERATION_FILTER_ADMIN" 
              type="Admin" 
              enabled="true"></channel>
                </channels>
                <templates>
                    <template tid="Operation-Filter-Messages">
                        <data name="ErrorMessage" inType="win:UnicodeString"></data>
                    </template>
                </templates>
            </provider>
        </events>
    </instrumentation>
    <localization>
        <resources culture="en-US">
            <stringTable>
                <string id="level.Error" value="Error"></string>
                <string id="OperationFilter.event.1.message" value="There was an error interacting with the database during an operation."></string>
            </stringTable>
        </resources>
    </localization>
</instrumentationManifest>
```

and here is the function that is responsible for writing to the event log:

```
DWORD writeToEventLog(LPWSTR message)
{
    DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    REGHANDLE RegistrationHandle = NULL;
    EVENT_DATA_DESCRIPTOR Descriptors[1];

    status = EventRegister(
        &OPERATION_FILTER,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &RegistrationHandle
    );

    std::wcout << L"message: " << message << std::endl;

    if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return status;
    }

    EventDataDescCreate(
        &Descriptors[0], 
        message,        //<----this won't show up even though I add it here
        sizeof(wchar_t) * (wcslen(message) + 1)
    );

    status = EventWrite(
        RegistrationHandle,
        &OPERATION_DB_ERROR,
        1,
        &Descriptors[0]
    );

    if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::wcout << L"Unable to write to event log" << std::endl;
    }

    EventUnregister(RegistrationHandle);
    return status;
}
```

I've put a comment on the event data I'd like to store. Anytime I issue a call to the above method, I in fact get an event written to the windows log but with empty event data. The message string that is passed into the function doesn't appear under the event data when I view these events in the windows event log. What am I missing here?

I was referencing the following example online found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ETW/writing-manifest-based-events). Am I just missing something totally obvious?

Comment: "windows event log" smells bad, that is not what you look at to see ETW event trace data.  There is a decent FAQ [located here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a1aa1350-41a0-4490-9ae3-9b4520aeb9d4/faq-common-questions-for-etw-and-windows-event-log?forum=etw).

Answer (score 0):

So I answered my own question here. I forgot to actually copy my file to the appropriate location. If you are going to do this you MUST be certain that you have properly copied the file to the resourceFileName and messageFileName locations. Otherwise you will get unexpected behavior from the event viewer.